# printing time in 24 hours format in unix

Tags: unix, time

write command to print time in 24 hour format in unix.

Comment: What do you have so far, and how doesn't it work?

Comment: `echo "time in 24 hour format"`

Comment: copying and pasting thankyou messages. that suck!

Answer (score 2):

Just use the `date` command:

Details:

```
man date
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Try:

```
date -d %R
```